# In electron a YouTube API upload returns status 200, and gives no error, but an upload doesn't occur. The same code works in regular NodeJS project

Tags: node.js, google-api, electron, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube v3 api from googleapis to upload a video to YouTube. When I do this the videos.insert function returns the following output (the bottom object):[image: image of output]

This takes about 5 seconds to execute, and returns status 200. However, the problem with this is that it doesn't actually upload the video, it does get inserted in my YouTube videos, but there is no data uploaded and YouTube shows a failed upload.
The problem doesn't lie in the authentication, as I can request channel info using the same OAuth2, and it doesn't return any error.

The weirdest thing to me is that the same code using the same googleapis library **does** work on a regular NodeJS project. It uploads the video correctly.

Does anyone know what might be different for Electron compared to NodeJS?

Request that's sent by Electron:
[image: Request body]

Electron upload function: https://github.com/RuurdBijlsma/MovieMaker/blob/master/movie-maker/src/plugins/vuex/auth-module.js#L69

```
async uploadVideo({commit, getters, rootState}) {
        console.log("Upload", filePath, service);
        commit('ytUpload', true);
        commit('ytDone', false);
        commit('ytProgress', 0);
        commit('ytUrl', '');

        let filePath = 'C:/Users/Ruurd/Videos/soep.mp4';
        let fileSize = fs.statSync(filePath).size;
        let title = 'What up gang my new rocet league video here';
        console.log("Uploading", title);
        let res = await service.videos.insert({
            auth: getters.oauth,
            part: 'snippet,status',
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    title,
                    description: 'how u doing'
                },
                status: {
                    privacyStatus: "unlisted"
                },
            },
            media: {
                mimeType: 'video/mp4',
                body: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            },
        }, {
            onUploadProgress: function (e) {
                console.log('progress', e.bytesRead / fileSize);
            }
        });
        console.log(res);
    },
```

NodeJS upload code: https://gist.github.com/RuurdBijlsma/bad525ce011a0d08eeece6e02a7d1c5b

```
async function upload() {
authorize();
let filePath = 'C:/Users/Ruurd/Videos/soep.mp4';
let fileSize = fs.statSync(filePath).size;
let service = google.youtube('v3')
let title = 'test1' + Math.random();
console.log("Uploading", title);
let res = await service.videos.insert({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    part: 'snippet,status',
    resource: {
        snippet: {
            title,
            description: 'test'
        },
        status: {
            privacyStatus: "unlisted"
        },
    },
    media: {
        mimeType: 'video/mp4',
        body: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    },
}, {
    onUploadProgress: function (e) {
        console.log(e.bytesRead / fileSize);
    }
});
console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code, not an image or a link to a third party site.

Comment: @RuteNL: check that the two instances of your program (the electron and the nodejs ones) *do make the same `POST` call* to `Videos.insert` endpoint (do check the two HTTP bodies for that matter).

Comment: @DaImTo I added code samples, but I'm quite sure the problem doesn't lie in that function seeing as that function works just fine on NodeJS. I understand readers of stackoverflow wanting to check it anyway, so i added it, but whatever the problem is it probably lies somewhere outside of the code samples

Comment: The reason to include your code is so that it may help someone in the future your link to a third party site may change in the future. Having it here could help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up moving the upload function to the main process in my electron application, and now it works. Not sure why that's needed though, I use plenty other Node only packages (express, fluent-ffmpeg, electron-context-menu) in my renderer and can use them by declaring them as node packages in the electronBuilder config (externals)

It's not a great solution imo, but it works for now. I still find it quite odd for it to fail uploading completely without any errors or warnings

Comment: My guess is the following: that's not a failed upload (from the perspective of the API) because the electron program *uploads an empty file*. You can confirm or refute my conjecture if checking the video in YouTube Studio.

Comment: @stvar I'm using the same file on both the electron and the nodejs instance, and checked the filesize before uploading (was correct, about 40 MB). Although this does seem like a very plausable solution, maybe the fs.createReadStream works differently in electron

Comment: OK; but that's not what I'm saying; again: please check the two HTTP bodies to be the same.

Comment: @stvar how do i check the body of the request in NodeJS?

Comment: Check the problematic one first; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65258928/8327971) shows the format of that body.

Comment: This is the request made by electron: https://i.imgur.com/VwHyVNV.png Main difference to the request format you sent I see is no content-transfer-encoding and no mime-version in the request payload. I don't know what the binary data is supposed to look like, but it's probably not there in my electron-made request. In my fixed version (with the request being made in the main process) the network request doesn't show up on the network tab in devtools

Comment: Your HTTP body shows an empty part: the second one, of type `video/mp4`. Thus you confirmed my conjecture. The API call is formally correct (you may double check that `316` is its length), but, you're uploading in fact an empty file. That also can be double-checked in YouTube Studio.

Comment: The reason of that I unfortunately cannot assess. You have to dig it further; it well may be a bug of the client library `GAPI` itself. As far as I know, this library is not open source (to my knowledge all other Google APIs client libraries are).

Comment: I'd propose that you paste as text the HTTP body within the question text above, then I'll add a short answer accounting for that. We'll do this for the sake of other SO users that might well came across the same issue (and possibly provide more input to it).

Comment: (If you'll confirm that YouTube Studio indeed shows you an empty upload file, then) I'd also propose to change the title of your post to: *In electron a YouTube API upload returns status 200, and gives no error, but an empty file upload occurs. The same code works in regular NodeJS project.*