# Understand why uploading video via curl returns an authentication error

Tags: curl, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload to YouTube via the API. I am doing so with `curl` and when am running following command I receive an error saying that am not unauthenticated, even though I have filled out the authentication details.

My code is:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'client_id: CLIENT_ID' -H 'client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET' -H 'auth_uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth' -H 'token_uri: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{
    "snippet": {
        "title": "Test Title",
        "description": "Test description",
        "tags": ["test", "tags"],
        "categoryId": 20
    },
    "status": {
        "privacyStatus": "unlisted"
    }
}' 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos'
```

Error message is `401`:

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

I have 100% put in the `client_id` and `client_secret` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, @Mac Hooper, your code suffers very badly from a whole lot of issues. Please bear with me for a while:

1. You have to acknowledge that video uploading (that is using the [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) API endpoint) has to be properly authorized:

> [**Authorization**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#auth)
> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)).
>
> **Scope**
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload`
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner`
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`

2. Uploading videos using the YouTube Data API cannot be done as simple as you're trying to do it. Although not officially documented as such, the API supports two kinds of uploading procedures:

   a. Resumable uploads, and
   b. One-go uploads.

The resumable uploads are achieved by means of the officially documented [Resumable Uploading Protocol](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol).

The resumable uploading protocol is quite tricky to correctly be implemented regardless of the implementation language/environment. Google provides open-source code that implements the protocol for a plethora of languages/environments. Although it is achievable, I'd recommend against implementing this protocol in shell scripts using `curl`.

On the other hand, uploading videos in one go is what you'll have to do if expecting to issue only one `curl` call per video upload (excluding the calls implied by the procedure of obtaining an access token). But that `curl` call requires certain things to be prepared beforehand.

There's [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65258928/8327971) that indicated the path to be taken when employing `curl` in one-go uploads.

Basically, your `curl` call would look like the one below:

```bash
$ curl \
--data-binary "@$MULTIPART_RELATED" \
--header "Content-Type: $CONTENT_TYPE" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=multipart&part=snippet,status'
```

(Do note that above I presume issuing `curl` at a `bash` command line prompt. When being at a Windows command line prompt things work similarly, but the above `curl` command should properly be adapted.)

The `curl` command above has three parameters: `$MULTIPART_RELATED`, `$CONTENT_TYPE` and `$ACCESS_TOKEN`. The latter is your credentials data that gets passed on to YouTube's server such that [your API call be authorized](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#curl-examples).

Do read the section [Obtaining OAuth 2.0 access tokens](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#obtainingaccesstokens) of the official document [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps) for to see how to obtain a valid (non-expired) access token upon completing successfully an OAuth 2 authentication/authorization flow.

The parameter `$MULTIPART_RELATED` is the name of the file you should have composed (programmatically) before issuing the actual `curl` call. The format of this file is not documented officially as such, but is derived upon inspecting Google's own open-source code.

The parameter `$CONTENT_TYPE` is a string that specifies the [`Content-Type` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387) needed by the HTTP `POST` method to be issued via `curl`.

Again, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65258928/8327971) to the SO question [How to upload video to youtube using google api. Without libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65258438/8327971) provides all the details for one to be able to generate properly the file `$MULTIPART_RELATED` and the string `$CONTENT_TYPE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the documentation for [video.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert?apix=true)  you will find an example of how the upload works in curl.

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{}' \
  --compressed
```

You appear to be missing a number of the headers that are required mainly that of the access token which is passed as a bearer token.  What you need to understand is that the `client_id` and `client_secret`  are used to CREATE the access token they do not by themselves grant you access to any data.

An access token needs to be created using the Oauth2 flow.  I have a [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/LindaLawton/cff75182aac5fa42930a09f58b63a309/raw/7ea13afe42462a809687fb9a6b8fa106e947ba86/GoogleAuthenticationCurl.sh%2520) that shows how this can be done. YOu will need to use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload` scope

```
# Client id from Google Developer console
# Client Secret from Google Developer console
# Scope this is a space seprated list of the scopes of access you are requesting.

# Authorization link.  Place this in a browser and copy the code that is returned after you accept the scopes.
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=[Application Client Id]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=[Scopes]&response_type=code

# Exchange Authorization code for an access token and a refresh token.

curl \
--request POST \
--data "code=[Authentcation code from authorization link]&client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

# Exchange a refresh token for a new access token.
curl \
--request POST \
--data 'client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&refresh_token=[Refresh token granted by second step]&grant_type=refresh_token' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Comment: Sorry, @DaImTo, but you're misleading the OP (which is very likely not an experienced API user as you are). You first `curl` command fails with the following error response: `{"error":{"code":400,"message":"The request does not include the video content.","errors":[{"message":"The request does not include the video content.","domain":"youtube.video","reason":"mediaBodyRequired","location":"body","locationType":"other"}]}}`.

Comment: The API error response is expected and correct, since your first `curl` command does not upload any sort of video content. Please read my answer to this post (that I did provided a few days ago) for to see how to upload a video file through a single `curl` command.

Comment: On the other hand, using the `POST` method on the URL `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos` is undocumented API (even it that should work somehow). That is so, in spite of the API explorer showing the URL under a `curl` command on the API Explorer window that's accessible on the [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) endpoint's official page.

Comment: Only one more (minor) thing (that could be confusing to an unexperienced API user): when providing an access token to an API endpoint for to issue an authorized request, using an API key along with that access token is superfluous (suffices to pass to the API only that access token).

Comment: Even if one issues a "fixed" `curl` command -- `curl --request POST "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status" --header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"  --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"snippet":{"title":"Test Title","description":"Test description","tags":["test","tags"],"categoryId":20},"status":{"privacyStatus":"unlisted"}}' --compressed` --, he/she will still obtain from the API the same `mediaBodyRequired` error response.