# How to insert video with Youtube Data API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to insert a video to YouTube with [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3), following [this example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) and using postman.

```
POST https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status
Authorization: Bearer <valid_access_token>
```

As for the body I'm using `form-data` with two key-value pairs:

- one of type `File` with key `file` and value the video I want to upload
- other of type `Text` with key `request` and value containing the json

[image: postman]
Json:

```
{
  "snippet": {
    "title": "Summer vacation in California",
    "description": "Had fun surfing in Santa Cruz",
    "tags": ["surfing", "Santa Cruz"],
    "categoryId": "22"
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "private"
  }
}
```

But I'm getting a `Bad Request`.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badRequest"
            }
        ],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [How to upload video to youtube using google api. Without libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65258928/8327971). Unfortunately, your attempts above are quite far away from the real solution. Please comment below if needing further help. See also [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66086618/8327971), which extends the answer I gave previously (mentioning a concrete `curl` command for uploading videos).

Comment: Just curious but is postman going to create a file stream for you to let you upload the video itself?